Add translation to app. angular.json issue
I want to add translations to the app and stuck with the configuration issue. I have the following angular.json file:
{
  "projects": {
  ...
     "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": "en-US",
        "locales": {
          "ru": {
            "translation": "src/locale/messages.xlf"
          },
        "browserTarget": {
          "tracker:build:development,ru"}
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      ...
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "ru":{"localize":["ru"]},
          ...
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "tracker:build"
          }
        }

I try to do ng serve --configuration=ru --open and got this
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "" must have required property 'browserTarget'.
Help me please to configure app.

Could you post the entire angular.json content? It's hard to say whether you made a typo somewhere or if there's something wrong with the configuration itself.

i can't it's because too log

Understandable! You can always use sites like Pastebin to paste the full log though.

thanks for the idea! This is my angular.json  https://pastebin.com/XAef9h16

In case someone has simmilar issue, please check this docs
https://angular.io/guide/i18n-example
with correct angular.json file, with translation.
